# Hide row base on cell value = zero

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there I have a problem in hiding the row that have it's Zero value on the two middle cells, the values on the middle cells generated dynamic from google spreadsheet ,the code below is good and hide the rows that have zero value written by me, but this code didn't catch the generated value.

What I want to do is to hide the row after the value generated?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.successota.com/dp/example.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.successota.com/dp/sortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        // Add your sheets url and range below

        var spreadsheetUrl = ""
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
        // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#methods
        // getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);
        // --1 --- ok
document.getElementById("B1B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);
document.getElementById("B1S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 1);
document.getElementById("B2B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(1, 0);
document.getElementById("B2S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(1, 1);
document.getElementById("B3B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(2, 0);
document.getElementById("B3S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(2, 1);
document.getElementById("B4B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(3, 0);
document.getElementById("B4S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(3, 1);
document.getElementById("B5B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(4, 0);
document.getElementById("B5S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(4, 1);
document.getElementById("B6B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(5, 0);
document.getElementById("B6S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(5, 1);
document.getElementById("B7B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(6, 0);
document.getElementById("B7S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(6, 1);
document.getElementById("B8B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(7, 0);
document.getElementById("B8S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(7, 1);
document.getElementById("B9B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(8, 0);
document.getElementById("B9S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(8, 1);
document.getElementById("B10B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(9, 0);
document.getElementById("B10S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(9, 1);
document.getElementById("B11B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(10, 0);
document.getElementById("B11S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(10, 1);
document.getElementById("B12B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(11, 0);
document.getElementById("B12S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(11, 1);
document.getElementById("B13B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(12, 0);
document.getElementById("B13S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(12, 1);
document.getElementById("B14B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(13, 0);
document.getElementById("B14S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(13, 1);
document.getElementById("B15B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(14, 0);
document.getElementById("B15S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(14, 1);
document.getElementById("B16B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(15, 0);
document.getElementById("B16S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(15, 1);
document.getElementById("B17B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(16, 0);
document.getElementById("B17S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(16, 1);
document.getElementById("B18B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(17, 0);
document.getElementById("B18S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(17, 1);
document.getElementById("B19B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(18, 0);
document.getElementById("B19S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(18, 1);
document.getElementById("B20B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(19, 0);
document.getElementById("B20S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(19, 1);
document.getElementById("B21B").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(20, 0);
document.getElementById("B21S").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(20, 1);
      } 
    </script>

    <script>
    setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds(); //convet 00:00 to seconds for easier caculation
    var fiveMin = 60 * 5; //five minutes is 300 seconds!
    var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin; // let's say 01:30, then current seconds is 90, 90%300 = 90, then 300-90 = 210. That's the time left!
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60; //formart seconds into 00:00 
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Time left to next 5 min update: "+result;

}, 500) //calling it every 0.5 second to do a count down
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideRow (){
//alert("Hello world");
var tbl = document.getElementById('TabCur');         //find the table
var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');        //find all rows in the table body

for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {                  //iterate through the rows

    var cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td');     //find all of the cells in the row

    var flag = true;                                //set flag prior to cell evaluation

    for(j = 1; j < cells.length-1  ; j++) {             //iterate through the cells (starting with the cell at position 2)
    alert(cells[j].text());
        if (cells[j].innerHTML != '0') {            //check if the cell contains '0' (set flag to false if cell is not '0')
            flag = false;                           
        }
    }

    if(flag) { 
        rows[i].classList.add('hide');              //hide the row if the falg remained true (i.e. none of the cells contained a value other than '0'
    }
}
}
</script>   
<style>
.hide { 
    display: none; 
}
</style>    
</head>
<body style="background-color:#f6fbfb;a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {color:#ffffff;}">

<div id="test" style="text-align: center;color:094f68;"></div>
samir
<table class="sortable" id="TabCur" style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%; height:20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color:#777777;border-width: 1px;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"><caption style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ccffff;"></span></caption>
<thead>
<tr style="background-color:#094f68;color:ffffff;line-height:50px">
<td style="text-align: center;" width="40%">A</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" width="10%">B</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" width="10%">C</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" width="40%">D</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr style="background-color:#f2eab3;line-height:30px">
<td>Test1</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B2B"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B2S"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: right;">test1</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f2eab3;line-height:30px">
<td>EAL</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B3B"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B3S"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: right;">Test2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f2eab3;line-height:30px">
<td>test3</td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B4B"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><p id="B4S"></p></td>
<td style="text-align: right;">Test3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f2eab3;line-height:30px">
<td>TEST4</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">0</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">TEST4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
<script>
window.onload = HideRow;
</script>
</html>
```

when I try to alert the output I found the problem in this line

```
 if (cells[j].innerHTML != '0') {
```

the code get this values :

```
<p id="B1S"></p>
<p id="B4S"></p>
<p id="B4S"></p>
0
```

the only last row is accepted and hide but the others return unmatched values

thanks .

Comment: Try firing your HideRow function just at the end of drawChart method.

Comment: @Bardo I did but nothing happened  i added this code at the end
<script>
window.onload = HideRow;
</script>

Comment: @Bardo  Can u show me how??

Answer (score 0):

I solved " thanks God "

using

```
if (cells[j].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML != '0')
```

instead of

```
 if (cells[j].innerHTML != '0') {
```

that's all

thanks for @Bardo and @Selim Ajimi for his good correction